# How to send parquet to kafka in batches using strcutured spark streaming?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I'am reading parquet files and convert it into JSON format, then send to kafka. The question is, it read the whole parquet so send to kafka one-time, but i want to send json data line by line or in batches:

```
object WriteParquet2Kafka {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("yarn")
      .appName("Write Parquet to Kafka")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val ds: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .schema(parquet-schema)
      .parquet(path-to-parquet-file)


    val df: DataFrame = ds.select($"vin" as "key", to_json( struct( ds.columns.map(col(_)):_*  ) ) as "value" )
      .filter($"key" isNotNull)

    val ddf = df
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("topic", topics)
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/test")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
      .start()

    ddf.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out how to solve my question, just add a `option` and set a suitable number for `maxFilesPerTrigger`:

```
    val df: DataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .schema(parquetSchema)
      .parquet(parqurtUri)
```

Note: `maxFilesPerTrigger` must set to 1, so that every parquet file being readed.